# How to connect two columns through a row in httml/css

Tags: html, css, angular, layout, flexbox

I am looking to create a layout where I have 3 columns and a few rows down, i am trying to connect two columns through a single row (the image explains it better than I do)

[image]

as you can see the second column is connected to the first one through the 3rd row, i haven't been able to achieve this connection

what's the best way to approach this with css and html (maybe js too?)?

for more information:

I am using angular for this project and scss

thanks!

Comment: What about flexbox rules? What have you coded so far?

Comment: all i have so far is 3 divs using flexbox for the columns:

div 1: has 2 inner divs and to separate them i have them as `justify-content: space-between`
div 2: has 3 inner divs with the content being `flex-flow: column`
div 3: same as div 2

Comment: if you post the code so far we can provide a more specific answer, but you should be able to do this with css grid using grid template arreas, see this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas